# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null--- But ID is there

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to use the web audio API and make an audio visualization.

Im following this [tutorial](http://ianreah.com/2013/02/28/Real-time-analysis-of-streaming-audio-data-with-Web-Audio-API.html) but i get this error :

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

in this part of the code:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
source.connect(context.destination);
```

});

I do have an id called player in the html like so :

```
<audio id="player" src="tune.wav"></audio>
```

My full code is this :

```js
var context = new AudioContext(); // Create audio container 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();



var dataArray = new Float32Array(bufferLength);

var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;
    analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(dataArray);
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;




var audioElement = document.getElementById("player");

audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    source.connect(context.destination);
});



function start(){ 

    
    request.open("GET", "tune.wav", true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as binary data 

    request.onload = function(){ 
        var data = request.response;        
        audioRouting(data);
    };  

    request.send(); 
}

function stop() { 
source.stop(context.currentTime); // stop the source immediately 
}

// Create Buffered Sound Source 
function audioRouting(data) { 
    source = context.createBufferSource(); // Create sound source 
    context.decodeAudioData(data, function(buffer){ // Create source buffer from raw binary 
    source.buffer = buffer; // Add buffered data to object 
    source.connect(context.destination); // Connect sound source to output 

    playSound(source); // Pass the object to the play function 
    }); 
}

// Tell the Source when to play 
function playSound() { 
source.start(context.currentTime); // play the source immediately 
}

console.log();


$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( ".play" ).click(function() {
    start();
    console.log("yo");
    });

    $( ".stop" ).click(function() {
    stop();
    });

});
```

Comment: Very likely because the element isn't there **yet**. You need to put your script at the bottom of the page, or invoke it when the [DOM is ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an initialization function (the callback of `$(document).ready`), yet you initialize `audioElement` outside of the function, therefore the element will not be ready.  You should instead declare the element outside the initialization function but initialize it inside the initialization function.

Comment: I did what you said, I declared audioElement at the top , outside the `$(document).ready)` function like so `var audioElement ;
`, and then initilized it inside it like so : `audioElement = document.getElementById("player");` But i now get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`   Any ideas ?

Comment: I would have to see the syntax to figure out the syntax error.